# How to apply CSS based on publishing date

Tags: css, date

Is there an idea in WordPress that can apply CSS file only to posts published after a certain date?

Renewal a site created with WordPress.
It is to keep the previous record and apply the design differently after the renewal.

Answer (score 2):

You can compare the post date to the date of your choice and enqueue different styles depending on the result:

```
<?php

function my_enqueue_styles_depending_on_date() {

    global $post;

    $style_switch_date = '20201230'; // the trigger date
    
    if ( is_single( $post->ID ) ) {

        $post_date = get_the_date( 'Ymd', $post->ID );

        if ( $post_date > $style_switch_date ) {
            wp_enqueue_style( 'css_for_newer_posts' );
        } else {
            wp_enqueue_style( 'css_for_older_posts' );
        }
    }
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue_styles_depending_on_date');
```

Make sure to `wp_register_script()` before you enqueue the style by it's name (handle) or use the full `wp_enqueue_style()` syntax.

Comment: Seems like a good solution, but I am not convinced about the original concept - perhaps there is a simpler way - such as different templates for older posts?

Comment: Thank you. That's good advice. I will proceed with the work and give you feedback.